# Change of SD after data removal

Tags: standard-deviation, means, data-analysis

I was asked to analysis 3 data, and calculate their mean and standard deviation (SD) to report the data as mean +/- SD. However, since one of it lied out of +/- 1 SD, should it be rejected?

If yes, since SD cannot be calculated by 2 data, then how can I report the 2 data by mean +/- SD? Or I should take the original SD to report the data?

Much thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: Do you mean you have only three data points? If so, it would be a shame to throw one of them out. That's an *extremely* small sample. There's no possible test of reliability with such a small sample. Unless this is an exercise, the data is probably meaningless.

Comment: Thanks for answering:) This is actually a data from practical lab so I've no choice...So should I keep all these 3 data instead of rejecting 1 out then?

Comment: You can calculate the standard deviation from 2 data points. And I don't think you should reject 1 out of 3 data points for being more than 1 standard deviation away from the mean.

Comment: I would keep all of the data. There's nothing wrong with a data point being 1 SD away from the mean. Even for a perfect normal distribution, about 99% of the data lies within 2 SDs. That's not all of it, and far less lies within 1 SD. I would say that if you could repeat the lab experiment to obtain several more samples, it would help any sort of statistical analysis. The analysis itself won't mean much, but if it's really just an exercise for the statistics, that's okay.

Comment: Thanks both of you :) I think I won't reject the data in this case then, since I only have limited data and the experiment cannot be performed again. It is just an exercise for us to practice data handling, no worries :D